# Which Textual Sources Discuss Proto-Judaism?

Tags: abraham, har-sinai

Abraham lived before Sinai. He initiated the 2000 years of Torah (see Avoda Zara 9a). But per the  *Parshat Derachim*, the *Mizrachi* posits that Abraham adopted/ushered in a mode of Judaism that is different than today's. A type of Proto-Judaism. *Mizrachi*, Exodus 4:24:

> ואף על פי שאברהם אבינו קיים כל התורה כולה... הוה מצי להחמיר על עצמו לקיים גם המצות שאינן מכלל הז' מצות שנצטוו בהן בני נח אע"פ שעדיין לא נצטוו בהן, אבל להתיר ... מי מצי להקל.

Abraham adopted Jewish stringencies, but could NOT utilize Jewish-law leniencies. He was a 'Jew,' but not a Jew.

The *Parshat Derachim* Drush 1 underscores this in the Mizrachi:

> . הֲרֵי מְבֹאָר מִדְּבָרָיו דִּסְבִירָא לֵהּ דְּמַה שֶּׁקִּיְּמוּ כָּל הַתּוֹרָה הוּא דַוְקָא לְהַחְמִיר עֲלֵיהֶם, אֲבָל לֹא לְהָקֵל מֵעֲלֵיהֶם מִמַּה שֶּׁחַיָּבִים בְּנֵי נֹחַ. אַלְמָא דִסְבִירָא לֵהּ דְּלֹא יָצְאוּ מִכְּלַל בְּנֵי נֹחַ לְהָקֵל.

For example - why was Abraham allowed to study Torah? A non-Jew may not (Sanhedrin 59a). This is a vital question - Abraham ushered in the 2000 years of Torah, and so he wasn't allowed to avail himself of the Jewish 'leniency' to study Torah **if** this was a disallowed practice for a gentile.

Per the *Parshat Derachim* in Drush One, however, the Torah during this Proto-Judaic period could be studied by absolutely anybody. The prohibition that only a Jew study Torah did not congeal until Sinai.

> גּוֹי שֶׁעָסַק בַּתּוֹרָה — חַיָּב מִיתָה, וְלֹא הֻתַּר לָהֶם לִלְמֹד אֶלָּא בְּשֶׁבַע מִצְו‍ֹת דִּידְהוּ, כִּדְאִיתָא בְּפֶרֶק אַרְבַּע מִיתוֹת (סנהדרין נט, א). מִשּׁוּם דְּמִידִי הוּא טַעְמָא אֶלָּא מִשּׁוּם דִּכְתִיב (דברים לג, ד): "תּוֹרָה צִוָּה לָנוּ משֶׁה מוֹרָשָׁה" — לָנוּ מוֹרָשָׁה וְלֹא לָהֶם, וְחַיָּבִים עָלֶיהָ מִשּׁוּם גָּזֵל. וְאִיכָּא מָאן דְּאָמַר מִשּׁוּם גִּלּוּי עֲרָיוֹת, וְאַל תִּקְרֵי 'מוֹרָשָׁה' אֶלָּא 'מְאֹרָשָׂה'. וְכָל הָנֵי טַעֲמֵי לָא שָׁיְכִי אֶלָּא מִסִּינַי וְאֵילָךְ שֶׁנִּתְּנָה תּוֹרָה, אֲבָל מִקַּמֵּי הָכֵי לָא שָׁיְכִי כְּלָל.

Thus it emerges that Abraham the quasi-Jew initiated the period of Torah during a time when Torah could be studied by absolutely anyone. The forgoing is exciting in the sense that it speaks to the metamorphosis that the אלפיים תורה and Judaism experienced.

Are there textual sources other than the *Parshat Derachim* that discuss proto-Judaism?

Comment: Ever seen this [Or Hachaim](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.49.3.1?ven=Or_Hachayim,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)? If not prepare to have your mind blown!

Comment: That's the locus classicus of this topic

Comment: See an annotated edition here https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48331&st=%d7%91%d7%9f+%d7%a0%d7%97&pgnum=18&hilite=dc5f18c9-49b1-4daf-8125-55adf9f7d66d which cross references to much of the other relevant material

Comment: Sefer Raziel, Sefer Noach and Sefer Chanoch come to mind...

Comment: @ Rabbi Kaii thank you for that tour-de-force Or Hachayim. And so Yaakov could marry two sisters due to personal expediency ... this is very different from the Parshat Derachim/Mizrachi approach: שֶׁכָּל זֶה הוּא אִי אָמְרִינַן דְּיָצְאוּ מִכְּלַל בְּנֵי נֹחַ לְגַמְרֵי, חֲשִׁיבִי רָחֵל וְלֵאָה כְּגֵר שֶׁנִּתְגַּיֵּר דְּלֵית בֵּהּ קֻרְבָה; אַךְ אִם לֹא יָצְאוּ מִכְּלַל בְּנֵי נֹחַ לְהָקֵל, אֵיךְ הֻתְּרוּ לוֹ רָחֵל וְלֵאָה, כֵּיוָן דְּלִבְנֵי נֹחַ חֲשִׁיבִי עֲרָיוֹת.